# How I can refresh activity on start Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I refresh or update activity when it is starting?

I have code ThemeSwitcher in SecondActivity, when I switch theme and return to MainActivity, theme is't changes, only when I restart an app

Answer (score 1):

You should open your MainActivity then finish your second activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then you should set your theme before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setYourTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```